# Why Ansible write for CentOS in ansible_os_family": "Debian" ? CentOS it is not RedHat family?

Tags: linux, ansible, centos

Why Ansible write for CentOS in ansible_os_family": "Debian" ?
CentOS it is not RedHat family for Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

Centos' family is RedHat, of course. Test it, e.g.

```yaml
    - command: cat /etc/centos-release
      register: result
    - debug:
        var: result.stdout
    - debug:
        var: ansible_os_family
```

gives

```yaml
  result.stdout: CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105

  ansible_os_family: RedHat
```

Comment: Your question was closed because they think it's not ``"a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"``. You can [edit] your question and insert your [mre] code causing the error. Then this might be considered ``"... software development."``. Good luck!